# How to reduce the size of a character separated string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a number of strings which look similar to this:

```
-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing_elit_sed_do_eiusmod_tempor
```

The above string has 12 tokens overall. How can I reduce it to an arbitrary number, say 6 or 10 ignoring the `-` and `_` separators from the string.For example the reduction would look like:

For 6:

```
-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-
```

For 10:

```
-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing_elit_sed_do_
```

or 11:

```
-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing_elit_sed_do_eiusmod_
```

Any idea of how to redue the strings in such way that the separators remain at the end and at the beginning of the string?

Comment: Use `re.split()` to split it into a list of tokens and separators. Then take a slice of the list, and then join them back together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
>>> a = '-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing_elit_sed_do_eiusmod_tempor'
>>> def find_separator(text, num) :
...     for i in range(len(text)) :
...         if text[i] in '-_' :num -= 1
...         if num == 0 :
...             return i+1
...     return len(text)
... 
>>> find_separator( a, 6 )
28
>>> a[:28]
'-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know the index of `_` or `-` in the string, then you can slice string.

```
x = '-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing_elit_sed_do_eiusmod_tempor'
index = []
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    if v == '-' or v == '_':
        index.append(i)
print(x[:index[6-1]+1])
print(x[:index[10-1]+1])
print(x[:index[11-1]+1])
```

Output

```
-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-
-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing_elit_sed_
-lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing_elit_sed_do_
```

Comment: you do a lot of unnecessary work, imagine the string being a few megabytes and you just need to find the first 6 words... looking past first 100 bytes is totally useless and waste of time

Comment: @lenik yes, I agree, yet it also has advantages when making loads of requests. clearly `[ x[:find_separator( x, i)] for i in range(100)]]` does a lot of unnecessary work in this condition.

Comment: Could you elaborate more why maybe this is more expensive? @lenik

Comment: @qwerty python is making it easier to be lazy. `xrange(10000000)` does not generate 10millions of numbers, but give them to you one-by-one. if you need to find the 6th character, just analyze the beginning of the string and ignore the rest. parsing the __whole__ string (nobody know how large it could be) is expensive and time consuming.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon “Premature optimization is the root of all evil” is a famous saying among software developers. Its source is credited to Donald Knuth.

Comment: @lenik  Okay, thank you, I like your attitude to defect.  :).